# global frame in move_base

Tags: ros, navigation, global-costmap, local-costmap, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am slightly confused regarding the global frame parameter that is set in the local_costmap.yaml and global_costmap.yaml files to run move_base. The "local" parameter specified global frame as odom and the "global_costmap" specifies it as map. What exactly is the significance of this? Additionally where is map coming from? I have odom being published by the controller of my robot however my map building is published at another topic. Does move_base generate map by itself? If so why can I not see it as a published topic?

The reason I ask this question is because I am facing the following problem: I send a Goal to the move_base action server to complete. /odom is set as the global frame in my local_costmap_params.yaml file. However the robot goes to a random position and sends back task successful. In other words it does not listen to data published by /odom. Since at task completion /odom is publishing a random pose that does not correspond to the Goal position I specified it to go to. Any inputs/ suggestions?

Thanks
Ammar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39991/global-frame-in-move_base/) by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 289 on 2012-07-27

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The map is a [costmap](http://www.ros.org/wiki/costmap_2d). The purpose behind the costmap is to have the local area around the robot freshly mapped to prevent collision with a dynamic object. The costmap also inflates the objects in the costmap to the user specified inflation radius. You can see it as a published topic, even in rviz. The Odom is not the same as the localized pose. [Odom](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom) starts when the motors turn. This is the robot's odometry frame. The robot localizes to the global frame.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2